# Forbidden exception

Tags: permissions

Our users when they log in they are unable to see their photos why can this be happening? They log in and the photos don't appear.

> 2020-11-25 20:08:04 [-][-][-][error][yii\web\HttpException:403] yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException in /var/www/craft3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php:158

Comment: Where is this happening? On the front-end of the site? In the control panel?

Comment: User logs in on the front end, once logged in goes to a user page he can see and the profile photo does not display, this trace is from the logs. There seems to be a permission issue so the assets don't show because system thinks user is not logged in but in fact user is

Comment: @Abaran
Have you found a solution?